# Whats wrong with my code to deploy an app

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny, shinyapps

This is the link https://posit.cloud/content/6788323. The app works well locally but not when I deploy it. There appear an image that says there is  no content.

This is

```
# Verificar y, si es necesario, instalar las bibliotecas faltantes
required_packages <- c("shiny", "readxl", "DT", "dplyr", "purrr")
installed_packages <- rownames(installed.packages())

for (package in required_packages) {
  if (!(package %in% installed_packages)) {
    install.packages(package)
  }
}

# Cargar las bibliotecas después de verificar e instalar
library(shiny)
library(readxl)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

# Obtener la ruta relativa al archivo Excel
excel_file <- "results_1950_2020_separar_regresar.xlsx"

# Cargar el dataframe
df <- read_excel(excel_file)

# Cambiar nombres de las columnas
df <- df %>%
  rename(
    Año = Year,
    Hombres = Predicted_Hombres,
    Mujeres = Predicted_Mujeres
  )

# Crear conjunto de datos para la suma de la AMG
df_AMG <- df %>%
  group_by(Año, `Grupos quinquenales de edad`) %>%
  summarise(
    Hombres = sum(Hombres),
    Mujeres = sum(Mujeres),
    .groups = "drop"
  ) %>%
  mutate(Municipio = "AMG")

# Unir al conjunto de datos original
df <- bind_rows(df, df_AMG)

# Definir UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Proyecciones de la población del AMG por grupos quinquenales de edad y sexo: 2025-2045"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("municipio", "Selecciona un Municipio:", choices = unique(df$Municipio)),
      selectInput("grupo", "Selecciona un Grupo de edad:", choices = unique(df$`Grupos quinquenales de edad`))
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      h3("AMG"),
      DTOutput("totalAMG"),  # Mantener esta línea para mostrar la primera tabla
      DTOutput("tableData")
    )
  )
)

# Definir server
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  total_AMG <- reactive({
    df %>%
      filter(Municipio == "AMG") %>%
      group_by(Año) %>%
      summarise(
        Hombres = sum(Hombres),
        Mujeres = sum(Mujeres),
        Total = Hombres + Mujeres,
        .groups = "drop"
      ) %>%
      mutate(
        Hombres = formatC(Hombres, format="f", big.mark=",", digits=0),
        Mujeres = formatC(Mujeres, format="f", big.mark=",", digits=0),
        Total = formatC(Total, format="f", big.mark=",", digits=0)
      )
  })
  
  filtered_data <- reactive({
    df %>%
      filter(Municipio == input$municipio, `Grupos quinquenales de edad` == input$grupo) %>%
      mutate(
        Total = Hombres + Mujeres,
        Hombres = formatC(Hombres, format="f", big.mark=",", digits=0),
        Mujeres = formatC(Mujeres, format="f", big.mark=",", digits=0),
        Total = formatC(Total, format="f", big.mark=",", digits=0)
      )
  })
  
  output$totalAMG <- renderDT({
    total_AMG()
  })
  
  output$tableData <- renderDT({
    filtered_data()
  })
  
}

# Lanzar la aplicación
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I am tryng to deploy the app with posit cloud. Where is my error? It works locally. Thank you community.i have created many proects and all fails, but there is an app that work well, I need help to deploy my app.

Help to deploy my app

Comment: Perhaps your app is not able to read the excel file.  Try keeping it in www folder.

Comment: Also remove all the parts before your `library()` calls - it handles that automatically

Comment: Can you share the excel file? This would allow us to run your code.